# Populate drop down list from the other list item sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

I need filled drop down list in a SharePoint page from other list item. I want that drop down list item from other list item. Please help, thank you. I don't know how to start with it.

Comment: Do you want two lists to have drop down fields that have the same options? Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use jQuery to fetch the items from the list. Please follow the code sample below to fetch items from a list:
Please refer to the below example where we are populating a DropDown(Select Control) with list items values fetched from a Sharepoint List where FieldName is equal to Alpha. You can modify results by modifying the CAML query. The variables in below code are the names to be replaced with your ListName, SiteName etc.

```
    var soapEnv = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                            <soapenv:Body> \
                            <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                            <listName>SPListName</listName> \
                            <viewFields> \
                                <ViewFields> \
                                    <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                                </ViewFields> \
                            </viewFields> \
                            <query> \
                                <Query> \
                                <OrderBy> \
                                <FieldRef Name='Title'/> \
                                </OrderBy>\
                                   <Where> \
                                       <Eq> \
                                       <FieldRef Name='FieldName'/> \
                                       <Value Type='Text'>"+ "Alpha" +"</Value> \
                                        </Eq> \
                                     </Where> \
                                  </Query> \
                                  </query> \
                            </GetListItems> \
                            </soapenv:Body> \
                            </soapenv:Envelope>";


    $.ajax({
        url: "http://servername/sitename/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });


 });
```

//The below function populates the data fetched from List to the drop down control.

```
    function processResult(xData, status) {

    $(xData.responseXML).find("z\\:row").each(function() {

        $("select[title='SelectControlID']").append("<option value='" + $(this).attr("ows_ID") + "'>" + $(this).attr("ows_Title") + "</option>"); 

    });             
}
```